# Live View in Dreamweaver shows login form instead of page content

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm editing a php page in Dreamweaver CS4 (or CS5 for that matter) and want to view it in either **Live View** or **Live Code**.  Because the page checks to be sure that the current user has been authenticated, Live Code displays the code from the Login page instead of the code from the page I'm really editing.

Is there some way of "fooling" Dreamweaver so that it thinks I'm already logged in?  (I could, of course, just comment out the code which checks for the authenticated user, but this is a pain and makes the one-click Live View/Live Code much less useful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort answer is no. With CS5 at least you can perform the log-in operation and continue with the viewing of your page (just tested it out with Follow Links Continuously selected the Browser Navigation toolbar options drop menu button on the far right of the toolbar. I'm pretty sure that CS4 does not have an option to follow links like CS5 can.

It is possible that you can set cookies that indicate that you're logged in and then check for that cookie's presence/proper value, but I don't think that that cookies will carry over from editing session within Dreamweaver to another session in Live View (as in open your file, it writes a cookie when in Live View and then you close Dreamweaver and then re-open the file an put it in Live View).

Comment: The Browser Navigation toolbar option "follow links continuously" was just what I was looking for!  I've just switched to CS5 so that works for me.